# OctoberCMS Rain User plugin not working or redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to build a basic one-page site that is restricted to members only.  However, I can't seem to get the User plugin working.  Below are the following two pages that I thought I would need to accomplish this:

Home (home.htm)

```
title = "Site name"
url = "/"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

[session]
security = "all"
==
{% component 'session' %}

{% if user %}
    <p>Hello {{ user.name }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Nobody is logged in</p>
{% endif %}
```

Login (login.htm)

```
title = "Login"
url = "/login/:code?"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

[account]
redirect = "home"
paramCode = "code"
==
<?php
function onStart() {
  //dump($this);
  Flash::success('Flash working!');
}
?>
==
{% partial 'messages' %}
{% component 'account' %}
```

Some things to note:

- the "default" layout is literally just some HTML around `{% page %}`
- the partial is just so I could test Flash messaging since the documentation says it uses it
- I have tried many different configuration and I know the homepage is not locked down at the moment -- I am just trying to get stuff working first

All of that being said, the issue is that I'm going to the following URL (if I'm running via `php artisan serve`): http://localhost:8000/login and try to login with some user I have setup.  I have made sure they are activated.  Registration is disabled.  Throttling is disabled.  Activation required is disabled.  But I put the credentials into the login form and then am taken to: http://localhost:8000/login?login=username&password=password

Any advice would be awesome.  I feel like I'm missing something so stupid and so small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it today thanks to October chat.  The issue was this was missing the AJAX framework provided with October.  Basically in October a "valid" theme uses the built in Jquery/AJAX frameworks with October.  This is the code I had to add to the layout to get things rolling:

```
<script src="{{['@jquery','@framework']|theme}}" ></script>
```

Comment: you can simply use this tag
 `{% framework extra %}` - extra option permits to use those features http://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/extras